# Algorithms and Data Structures : should I study language specific books or generic books?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I wanted to study algorithms and data structures in detail (in the quest of becoming a better programmer :P ), i have been programming for 2-3 years (c++, java, python)

searching on google confused me between two type of books/web-resources

should i go for the books that are language specific like 
[http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Using-Python/dp/0470618299/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1320183104&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470618299)

or a generic book like 
[http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201000237](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201000237)

these are just examples, the main question is what type of resource should i choose, something language specific or generic? would there be a difference in anyway?

also, suggest a good web-resource/book (free is better) where i can accumulate good amount of knowledge in detail regarding algorithms and data structures. math is no issue

Note: i know there are many similar questions but my doubt is, would your study of algorithms and data structures depend on what programming language you use?

thanks,
Shobhit,

Comment: Algorithms and data structures are language agnostic - look at [CLRS](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1320185216&sr=1-1) (heavy math), Skiena's [*Algorithm Design Manual*](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Steven-Skiena/dp/1848000693/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (lighter math), or Berkeley [*Algorithms*](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html) (haven't read, but you can get their near-final draft free).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pluses and minuses to learning about algorithms and data structures in a language-specific way. On the plus side, the examples, exercises, and explanations can be very concrete. Provided you have access to an execution environment for that language, you can experiment on your own with the concepts as you are learning them. This is very powerful.

On the minus side, it is harder to distinguish between the core concepts (e.g., nodes and links in a tree) and the language-specific methods for implementing them (e.g., structs and pointers in C). Other languages may be so different (e.g., Prolog), that the core concepts may be totally unrecognizable if you haven't learned how to separate them from the language-specific aspects of what you have learned. There's also the problem that there are usually lots of language-specific stuff that are entirely a distraction from the core concepts. (malloc/free in C; constructors and destructors in C++, etc., -- unless you're studying memory management algorithms.)

One way to have the benefits of a language-specific presentation and also address its shortcomings is to study the same material presented for two radically different languages. The entire family of Algol-like languages (C, C++, Pascal, Algol, Java, C#, etc.) are basically equivalent for this purpose. I mentioned Prolog before; you might also consider Lisp. Another interesting approach might be a 4GL language like SQL. If you can implement a good balanced tree in a C program and also in an SQL schema and set of queries, then you can be confident that you have mastered the underlying concepts involved in balanced trees.

Comment: thanks, your explanation cleared my doubt completely. i think i would study something non specific like this CLRS book at first, and then learn how these are practically implemented specific to a language.

Comment: @Optimus - That's a good approach. You might also consider studying the theory and the practice in parallel. One book not mentioned so far that I would recommend is [Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Structures-Prentice-Hall-Automatic-Computation/dp/0130224189/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1320205297&sr=1-1) by Nicklaus Wirth. Although it dates from 1976, the only thing dated about the content is its use of Pascal. You can read it as a "theory" book or install a Pascal compiler and hack away. :)

Comment: is it really worth learning pascal for, as far as i know pascal does not contain even an auto-sizing string data-structure

Comment: @Optimus - Unless you're programming in Delphi, no--Pascal isn't worth learning for its own sake. However, Wirth's book is a true classic and, in my opinion, still one of the best books for learning about algorithms and data structures. You won't find a better presentation of recursion anywhere. Read some of the reviews at Amazon and you'll get an idea of why this programming book is still popular after 35 years.

Comment: turns out one of my friend has a copy of 'Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs' which he'll lend to me :) so i guess i'll dive into it first

Answer (score 2):

You should get [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) to start with. Language agnostic. In terms of algorithms, language doesnt make much difference. It s the theory/concept and how the algorithm works. that s what you need to learn.

Once you learn the concept, you can write the algorithm in any language of your choice.

This is due to the Complexity. Languages doesnt make a difference in terms of algorithms and complexity but the actual algorithm.

In respond to @birryree, Skienna's book, if you ask me is great to prepare for exams. I felt like there were just lot of puzzles. There is also [Kleinberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321295358), and [computer algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201612445). CLRS is the bible.

Comment: I've heard implementations of data structures are different in different languages, which sometimes effects the choice of best algorithm

Comment: I agree with you - I love CLRS (I used to work for Rivest's company too), and I've read Skiena's book more recently. I like Skiena's writing style and it's good for keeping my general algorithms knowledge up. CLRS is extremely dry reading and might scare readers away because of its density.

Comment: @Optimus not really, what you need to understand is Complexity / Asymptotic notation first. Algorithms are computed and considered based on asymptotic notation , ie: complexity.

Comment: well i think i should understand Complexity first ( not a compsci major so don't understand a lot of trivial concepts yet :P)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading both types of books. Generic books will basically guide you on the WHYs of the topic and Programming language specific usually tells you HOWs of the topic. So I recommend use both as they have their own significance.

Answer (score 1):

Most Algorithms and Datastructures book are very language-independent. Some use pseudocode, some don't even *have* that much code and one of [my favourite books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201066726) used Pascal, of all things.

Comment: is there some actual advantage in using pascal for practicing while studying algorithms?

Comment: No, it just happens that the book was written in it. I never even ran the Pascal code :P

Comment: :) sounds like something i would do